# I wish to execute a macro with enter key

Tags: macros, execute

I have a macro/Sub that I wish to run everytime the enter key is pressed. Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: Your question is a way too broad to answer. Please be *much* more specific. Also tell (in your tags) which programming language you are planning to use.

Answer (score 0):

Excel on Enter Macro

How to run a macro when certain cells change in Excel
Right-click the Sheet1 tab and then click View Code. 
The module sheet behind Sheet1 is opened.
Type the following code into the module sheet:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) Dim KeyCells As Range. ...

Click Close and Return to Microsoft Excel on the File menu.